# InnoSetup, How to change the color of RichEditorViewer

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I need to change the font color property of the `RichEditorViewer` of the default pages, but I can't find the control names or property name, I need help with this...

The `RichEditorViewer` of the `InfoBeforePage` (I need to change the font color):

[image: Setup screenshot]

This is the code I'm using:

```
const
  Custom_Height = 570;
  Custom_ProgressBar_Height = 30;
  Page_Color = $7b2b68;
  Page_Color_Alternative1 = clblack;
  Page_Color_Alternative2 = clwhite;
  Font_Color = $fffbff;

var
  DefaultTop,
  DefaultLeft,
  DefaultHeight,
  DefaultBackTop,
  DefaultNextTop,
  DefaultCancelTop,
  DefaultBevelTop,
  DefaultOuterHeight: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin

  DefaultTop := WizardForm.Top;
  DefaultLeft := WizardForm.Left;
  DefaultHeight := WizardForm.Height;
  DefaultBackTop := WizardForm.BackButton.Top;
  DefaultNextTop := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  DefaultCancelTop := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
  DefaultBevelTop := WizardForm.Bevel.Top;
  DefaultOuterHeight := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height;

  // Pages (Size)
  WizardForm.Height := Custom_Height;
  WizardForm.InnerPage.Height := WizardForm.InnerPage.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicensePage.Height := WizardForm.LicensePage.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);

  // Pages (Color)
  WizardForm.color := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.FinishedPage.Color  := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.InfoBeforePage.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.InnerPage.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.InstallingPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.LicensePage.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.PasswordPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.PreparingPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.ReadyPage.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.SelectComponentsPage.Color  := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.SelectDirPage.Color  := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.SelectProgramGroupPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.SelectTasksPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.UserInfoPage.color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.WelcomePage.color := Page_Color;

  // Controls (Size)
  WizardForm.InfoAfterMemo.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height :=  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height := Custom_ProgressBar_Height
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.Taskslist.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight - DefaultBevelTop));
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.Height  := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight - DefaultBevelTop));

  // Controls (Location)
  WizardForm.BackButton.Top := DefaultBackTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.Bevel.Top := DefaultBevelTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Top := DefaultCancelTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Top := WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Top + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.NextButton.Top := DefaultNextTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.Top := DefaultTop - (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight) div 2;
  //WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := (DefaultHeight / 2)

  // Controls (Back Color)
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.InfoAfterMemo.Color := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Color := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Color := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.MainPanel.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.PasswordEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.Color := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.Taskslist.Color := Page_Color;
  WizardForm.UserInfoNameEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.UserInfoOrgEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;
  WizardForm.UserInfoSerialEdit.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative2;

  // Controls (Font Color)
  WizardForm.FinishedHeadingLabel.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.InfoafterMemo.font.Color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.FinishedLabel.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.DirEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.Font.color := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.GroupEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.MainPanel.font.Color := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.PasswordEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.Taskslist.font.Color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.UserInfoNameEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.UserInfoOrgEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.UserInfoSerialEdit.font.Color  := Page_Color_Alternative1;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2.font.color  := Font_Color;
  WizardForm.ReadyMemo.font.Color := Page_Color_Alternative1;
end;
```

Comment: Correct name for this page is InfoBeforePage which is: property InfoBeforePage: TNewNotebookPage; read; of TWizardForm = class(TSetupForm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple RTF document with many attributes changed:

[image]

And here is appropriate code for it:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\deflang1051{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
>   Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}} {\colortbl
>   ;\red0\green77\blue187;\red255\green0\blue0;} {*\generator Msftedit
>   5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 Hello. This is \cf1 blue text\cf0 . \cf2 And this text is red\cf0 .
>   This is \i italic \i0 & \b bold\b0 .\par \f1 Even changing font to
>   Times is possible. \fs44 This text is 22 size.\f0\fs22\par \par \par }

Changing the color is possible with flag **\cfX** your text here **\cf0** where X is your desired color number.

Colors are saved in colortbl in the head of document (as RGB values, black is missing):

```
{\colortbl;\red0\green77\blue187;\red255\green0\blue0;}
```

so black = cf0, blue = cf1, red = cf2 etc.

To assing new text simply assign your new text to RTFText variable:

```pascal
WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText := '{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\deflang1051{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green77\blue187;\red255\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 Hello. This is \cf2 blue text\cf0 . \cf2 And this text is red\cf0 . This is \i italic \i0 & \b bold\b0 .\par
\f1 Even changing font to Times is possible. \fs44 This text is 22 size.\f0\fs22\par
\par
\par
}';
```

In the example above I changed color of blue text to red.

Comment: Awesome example, I've learned a lot, thankyou.   Do you know if I can use a variable into the property value? for example: `const Font_Color = cf0; WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText := '{\rtf1\blablabla\Font_Color}'` ¿?

Comment: Oh another little question, I can preserve the text data when changing the .RTFText property? (To preserve the InfoBeforeFile.txt document as text inside the RichEditor)? sorry if I ask too much, but I can't find any info on the web. Maybe I will need something as "SaveStringToFile()" function but the reverse "SaveFileToString()".

Comment: Yes, you can use variables. e.g. const FontColor: AnsiString = 'cf0'; WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText := '{\rtf1\blablabla\' + FontColor + '}'

Comment: Simply store old text in your variable: var OldText: AnsiString; Oldtext := WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText;

Comment: I did what you said, store the text and all with your code examples but then in the line to change the rtf text I get an error saying "Write-only property" and I cannot change the text. If I delete the var Oldtext I can modify the rtftext again... I don't understand it.

Comment: I am not sure what you need, please create new question and paste your code there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123879/innosetup-how-to-load-a-custom-text-into-rtftext

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for **InfoBeforeMemo**: TRichEditViewer component which is located on page **InfoBeforePage**

This page (NewNotebookPage) is property of TWizardForm (TSetupForm).

Here we go:

```
TRichEditViewer = class(TMemo)
  property RTFText: AnsiString; write;
  property UseRichEdit: Boolean; read write;
end;
```

So you need to change property **RTFText** which is pure AnsiString.

That means it is pure text, there is no property 'Font' or similar.
RTF text is simple text in special format which looks like this:

> {\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard This is some {\b
>   bold} text.\par }

So if you need to change the font you need to parse it manually - e.g. by changing *fswiss Helvetica* to your desired font and saving everything back.

More info about RTF here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: **if you need to change the font you need to parse it manually - e.g. by changing fswiss Helvetica to your desired font and saving everything back.** Thankyou for your answer but I don't understand that part, you can give a example of how to change the font color? and then I need to change the value of the property **RTFText** to what value?