# InnoSetup, How to load a custom text into RTFText

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, rtf, pascalscript

I'm trying to store the text of InfoBefore textfile into a variable and then load it into the RTFEditor with a custom font color and backcolor.

When I try to load the text from the variable it says "Write-only property"

I need a explicit example of how to do this two things together (Store the text in the var, load the text in the RTF with a custom color and backcolor) without complicating the things too much because I don't know Pascal.

This is the code:

```
const
 FontColor: AnsiString = 'cf0'; 
 BackColor: AnsiString = 'cf1'

 var
  OldText: AnsiString; 

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin

// I try to store the text in a variable
Oldtext := WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText; 

// I try to load from the variable, with a new font color for ALL the text, and a new BackColor.
WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.RTFText := Oldtext + FontColor

end;
```

Comment: The `TRichEditViewer` class doesn't have a read access of `RTFText` property so without Windows API, there's no way to read RTF text from there. So there's actually no *without complicating the things*.

Comment: To be more specific, RTF read implementation for the `TRichEditViewer` control is about [`EM_STREAMOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774304(v=vs.85).aspx) message and its [`EditStreamCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774368(v=vs.85).aspx) callback function, which you'll need to wrap by some [`external library`](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54).

Comment: omg... seems excesive hard, thankyou for the info guys. any other way to store the InfoBeforeFile inside a var?

Comment: No, I'm afraid that's the only possible way (except modifying `TRichEditViewer` class and making a new build of InnoSetup). You were going to modify font, didn't you ? There's also a different way how to modify font properties of a certain text in rich edit (more straight in my view), through the [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230(v=vs.85).aspx) message. Sorry, I'm not posting answers since I'm quite demotivated here these days, but if you want, I can post an example of its use (it's much easier than struggling with a raw RTF).

Comment: @TLama Thankyou so much for your help, if you want and you can post a answer where I can do what I need by following your steps (copy&paste) then do it and thanks again, but otherwise I really can't do that 'cause never touched Pascal or intended to learn it more of the necessary to use it with this InnoSetup script, maybe you can think the answer will be a waste of time for that reason so don't worry if you don't want answer, but can be usefull for other people too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to modify it after the fact, simply load your .txt file in WordPad, make the formatting changes you require, then save it in .rtf format.  You can then use this file as your `InfoBeforeFile` directly, without using any code.

Edit: if you want to change the background colour of the entire memo then you'll still need one line of code.  For example:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Color := clBlack;
end;
```

Comment: wow seems the better option, thanks, do you know if I can change the backcolor too with that method? can't give an example of a text with blank backcolor and black textcolor?

Comment: Yes and no.  As far as I am aware, RTF does not specify a way to define the background colour of the page as a whole, only of individual paragraphs.  (And WordPad does not provide a way to set the background colour of paragraphs, but it does let you set the highlight colour, which has a similar effect -- though you won't need it if you change the whole memo.)  If you want to change the background colour of the entire memo as a whole then you'll still need one line of code, which I've edited into my answer above.